# My <nav> <ul> isn't working in Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

My nav ul isn't working, i typed in 'ul>*li>a)*5 to create 5 of the ul's but it doesn't work, here's my source code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
        <title>CSS layout</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
              ul>(li>a)*5 
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div>

        </div>

        <footer></footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have emmet installed? Makesure you press tab at the end of the line

Comment: im using sublime text

Comment: Please visit this link and follow the instructions. You'll get what you want. http://shoogledesigns.com/blog/blog/2012/08/21/boost-your-sublime-text-2-with-zen-coding/

Comment: @ahruss I got emmet installed but when i do ul>li*5>a it only prints one line instead of 5

Answer (score 1):

go to on this  [site](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) copy package

after then open your sublime text editor {view > show console } paste inside

after then press{<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shif</kbd> > <kbd>p</kbd>} now type {install package} after install

again press {<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shif</kbd> > <kbd>p</kbd>} type{emmet} install and restart your sublime text, 2 or   3.

[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXfCQIlztuk)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using emmet too and it prints correctly

```
<ul>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>
```